# How to remove empty string data from an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am getting an array from php server like:

```
<__NSArrayM 0x7fe6326f2340>(
 01460367533.jpg,
 01460353708.jpg,
 01460354725.jpg,
 01460363165.jpg,
 01460364760.jpg,
 01460367938.jpg,
 ,
 11460353708.jpg,
 ,
 ,
 ,
 11460363173.jpg,
 11460364762.jpg,
 ,
 ,
 21460353708.jpg,
,
)
```

How can I remove empty string data (,) in `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: why and how are you adding the empty strings into the array to begin with?

Comment: agree with @Wain. just put a filter if it is empty just don't add it.

Comment: in server side i am getting this data how would i able to overcome this issue.

Comment: no idea, we know nothing about the server or the data, but when it arrives at the device you're still processing that and adding it to the array, what code does that?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a non-empty array from mutable array.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length > 0"];
NSArray *anotherArray = [yourMutableArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Agree with the first comment, though. You should take care of it while adding data to array.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove multiple occurrence of multiple strings/objects.

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"hello", @"", @"HI", @" ", nil];

[arr removeObjectsInArray:@[@"", @" "]];

NSLog(@"%@", arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest just use this simple one line of code

```
[mutableArrayOfStrings removeObject:@""];
```

to remove empty string items from your mutable string array.